# How does one set columns in a .txt file (CSV) to variables? (PYTHON)

Tags: python, csv, variables

I've been looking everywhere trying to figure out in how to assign variables to columns in CSV TXT FILES (PYTHON.)

Leeroy,19,7,12

Jenkins,19,8,11

Tyler,19,0,19

Napoleon Wilson,19,7,12

Big Boss,19,7,12

Game Dude,19,5,14

Macho Man,19,3,16

Space Pirate,19,6,13

Billy Casper,19,7,12

Otacon,19,7,12

Big Brother,19,7,12

Ingsoc,19,5,14

Ripley,19,5,14

M’lady,19,4,15

Einstein100,19,8,11

Dennis,19,5,14

Esports,19,8,11

RNGesus,19,7,12

Kes,19,9,10

Magnitude,19,6,13

How would I assign these columns to variables

I.E : name, scrore, score1, score 2 etc

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using `pandas`?

Follow this link to learn more about it.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: illl have a look, ty

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
line = 'Leeroy,19,7,12'
name, score, score1, score2 = line.split(',')
```

Or, more generally, like this.

```
name = []
score = []
score1 = []
score2 = []
with open('input.csv') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        tokens = line.split(',')
        name.append(tokens[0])
        score.append(tokens[1])
        score1.append(tokens[2])
        score2.append(tokens[3].strip())
```

Comment: Isn't that just setting "Leeroy" to name   not the whole column

Comment: Yes. You should do like this in a `for` loop.

Comment: That seems so complex, could you please show me ? Sorry to bother you :/